# Download file from absolute path

Tags: php, header, readfile, absolute-path

I am trying to download a file from an absolute path, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$fileurl = '/home/mydomain/public_html/wp-content/uploads/312tekstsecure3.pdf';
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileurl);
readfile( $fileurl );
```

Comment: As your variable name is `$fileurl`, you should have `readfile( $fileurl );` as well.

Comment: Sorry. Made a typo in the question. I am using the same string.

Comment: I think I got it working, but for same reason the returned file has the whole file path as name. Can I avoid this? Ie: -home-mydomain-public_html-wp-content-uploads-safefiles-312tekstsecure3.pdf

Comment: Yes, you can use `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fileurl));` to set the filename without the whole path.

Comment: Great! That works perfect. Can I also change the content-type to allow downloading any filetype?

Comment: Sure. If you want to read the content type directly from the file, use `finfo_file()` like this: `$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileurl); finfo_close($finfo); header("Content-type:" . $mime);` instead of just `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`.

Comment: When doing that, it wont download the file :-)

Comment: And when echoing $mime, it seems to be empty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change just one line.

```
<?php 
$fileurl = 'yourpath/file.pdf';
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileurl);
readfile( $fileurl );
?>
```

Comment: Please upvote my answer also so it can be helpful to others thanks :).

Comment: What is the difference between the question and the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
readfile($fileurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file exists and the server has correct access rights to this file? What about `Content-Length` header?